# what is the cost of using std::visit

Tags: c++, std-variant

Consider the following code ([run it](https://godbolt.org/z/v8xKMcsTr))

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <variant>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    Student(const char* name) : name(name) {}
    void display() { fmt::print("Student {}\n", name); }
    virtual play() { fmt::print("Student {} played\n", name); }
};

struct Teacher {
    std::string name;
    Teacher(const char* name) : name(name) {}
    void display() { fmt::print("Teacher {}\n", name); }
    virtual play() { fmt::print("Teacher {} played\n", name); }
};

int main() {
    // case 1: use Student
    Student student{"Alice"};
    student.display();

    // case 2: use std::variant which holds a Student
    std::variant<Student, Teacher> person(std::in_place_type<Student>, "Charlie");
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        arg.display();
    }, person);
}
```

What is the cost of case 2 comparing to case 1?

Does it only need to identify the type (using some saved index) and then do a `reinterpret_cast` like operation and then invoke the `display` member function?

Another question as raised by @alfC: if I change the above `main` to call `play` instead of `display`, which is a virtual function, will the cost be different?

Comment: This is *not* a fair comparison. It would make more sense to compare it the call of a virtual function call. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eeESJQk-mw

Comment: This is comparing two unrelated things.

Comment: @user3840170 why they are complete unrelated? I need to know what std::visit does under the scene before the function call is invoked

Comment: @alfC Thanks for pointing out the virtual function call. I edited the PO. Thanks also for  recommending the video. I will take a look

Comment: Because `std::variant` and `std::array` are not the same data structure. There is even a certain formal sense in which they are almost diametrically opposed.

Comment: If I change the case 1 to a simple `Student student{"Alice"}`, will this make the comparison be more reasonable

Comment: _what is the cost of using std::visit_ To answer the title of the question, probably much the same as a `switch` statement, just neater.

Comment: @PaulSanders you answered to the point that I am keen to know. Does it involves something like this: 
`switch (person.index) {case 0: reinterpret_cast<Student&>(internal_data).display(); break; ...`
If yes, could you please post as an answer?

Comment: I would expect it to, yes.  [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) is good for answering questions like this because you can inspect the code emitted by the compiler.

Comment: I cannot quite read assembly code. Could you please point to which part corresponds to the switch?

Comment: Godbolt highlights source lines and the corresponding assembly code in the same colour, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

> Complexity
> When the number of variants is zero or one, the invocation of the callable object is implemented in constant time, i.e. it does not depend on sizeof...(Types).

So it forbids if-chain and force something similar to a virtual call.

> If the number of variants is larger than 1, the invocation of the callable object has no complexity requirements.

So depend more about implementation: might be a layer by variant, or a bigger layer to handle the combination.

[As-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) might allow optimization such as de-virtualization.

And as always with performance, you have to measure for your specific cases.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate a litle on how gcc or/and clang handles it? Is it something like a `switch` as pointed out by Paul Sanders in the comment?